# Request Ajax in Live Server doesn't work for printing

Tags: ajax, laravel, printing

my cashier project build in laravel. i need print receipt from web browser via mobile bluetooth.

i use [mike42/escpos](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) and [RawBT](https://rawbt.ru/start.html) package.

my program is working fine when running in localhost. but, doesn't work in live server

this is my **VIEW** :

```
<button
   onclick="ajax_print('{{url('/cashier/pay',[$id])}}',this)"
   class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Pay
</button>
```

this is my **AJAX**

```
function ajax_print(url, btn) {
    b = $(btn);
    b.attr('data-old', b.text());
    b.text('wait');
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        window.location.href = data;  // main action
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("ajax error");
    }).always(function () {
        b.text(b.attr('data-old'));
    })
}
```

and this is my **Controller** :

```
try{    
    $profile = CapabilityProfile::load("POS-5890");
    $connector = new RawbtPrintConnector();
    $printer = new Printer($connector, $profile);
        
    // Content
    $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
    $printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
    $printer->text("Hello World.\n");            
                    
    //Print
    $printer->cut();
    $printer->pulse();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      return redirect()->route('cashierindex')->with('error','Something Error');
  } finally {
      $printer->close();
  }
```

Can you help me, why this code doesn't work in live server, but working fine in localhost ?

Comment: Which type of exception it is throwing in catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that is a touch little bit of problem..

in mike42 you have to spark off the requirement personal home page extension to your server. in your case, you forgot activating required extension

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a little bit of problem..

in [mike42](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) you should activate the requirement php extension in your server. in my case, i forgot activating **intl** extension